# Replacing corrupted iTunes App in High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, itunes

The iTunes app on my MBP was corrupted by a failed software update.  The app cannot be opened or trashed.  Is there any way to replace it short of a complete macOS reinstall?

Comment: See if you can remove any of the subcomponents and if so whether you can now remove iTunes :  Apple Software Update
Apple Mobile Device Support
Bonjour
Apple Application Support

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the OS from Recovery. It will only take about half an hour & will leave all your data intact.

I wouldn't suggest trying to pick it apart manually, or from Time Machine, as you won't know which components were corrupted & you will be fighting SIP all the way.

Apple only makes certain builds directly available & I'm not certain which build should be on High Sierra - https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes